# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3/TLS write client hello)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-6

When I try sending an email using Actionmailer, I get the following error...

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3/TLS write client hello)
```

My system is OS X 10.13.6, Ruby 2.7.3 w/openSSL, and Rails 6.0.3.7

### Console:

```
2.7.3 :003 > OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION
 => "OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021" 
2.7.3 :004 > OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
 => "OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021"
```

Comment: The error appears to be happening during the opening of the connection. This is indicated first by `state=SSLv3/TLS write client hello`, and second by searching `openssl/ossl_ssl.c` for this error (it's in a function named `ossl_start_ssl`). It could be a certificate problem. You might try to reproduce the error using `openssl s_client -connect _ -showcerts -state`, which should give you more information about the error.

Comment: Can you post actionmailer config you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that error when trying to establish TLS connection right away instead of upgrading through STARTTLS. Try using [mailsnag.com](https://mailsnag.com) or similar service and test with STARTTLS. It gives you sample config for Rails to test sending email with real SMTP server that is sandboxed (no email actually gets delivered).